# Какое слово является правильным?

Tags: грамматика

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно: "Шумеры были первым народом, изобреТшим элементарную систему письма" или изобреВшим... В словарях разные сведения: в одном — "изобреВшим", в другом — "изобреТшим".

Comment: Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно: "Шумеры были первым народом, изобреТшим элементарную систему письма" или изобреВшим ..... В словарях разные сведения: в одном -"изобреВшим", в другом -"изобреТшим".
Это мой вопрос.

Comment: Артем, а на вопрос ответить грамотности и знаний не хватило? Даже в печатных изданиях не обращают внимания на правильное употребление тире и дефисов. Смысл вопроса от этого не меняется.   Мне срочно нужен был ответ, а не оформление текста и исправление ошибок. "Здравствуйте." и следующее предложение, начинающееся с заглавной буквы, ошибкой не является.     Текст Вы откорректировали, а ответил на вопрос другой человек, который оказался более грамотным.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно "изобре**т**ший" (сов. вид; по отношению к одному случаю изобретения) и "изобрета**в**ший" (несов. вид; занимавшийся изобретательством).